# Scope to records which have associated records meeting certain conditions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a `Customer` model where each customer has many jobs:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer

  def self.unbilled
    finished.uninvoiced # these are other scopes on Job
  end
end
```

How do I define a scope on `Customer` which will return a list of all customers who have unbilled jobs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be able to [merge](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge) the scopes:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs

  scope :freeloaders, joins(:jobs).merge(Job.unbilled)
end
```